# SQL Server 2012 - Finding Missing Dates

Tags: date, sql-server-2012, missing-data

I have a table of stock prices but some dates are missing.

How do I generate a list of missing dates for each stock ticker?

[image]

Comment: Just using T-SQL? Or?

Comment: SQL Server 2012